# Random Delay Generator for Workflow Foundation

Tags: c#

Problem statement: In Windows Workflow Foundation we have a long running state machine.  We had an issue with SQL server deadlocks putting workflows into a suspended state.  Since Workflow instances are independent actors, we cannot easily coordinate these calls.  As part of our workflow error handling strategy, if the offending activity receives a sql exception, we want to delay and try again and do this in a loop up to a certain number of retries.

We need a (semi) random int. Now the proper thing to do is generate one random list and use the next(min,max), but each workflow instance is an independent actor and I don't want to make a central service just for this.

My strategy, is by using the leftmost digits of DateTime->Ticks as the random seed, this will generate a random enough number for a delay activity. The plan is that eventually all workflows will advance to their next state.  Performance is not a concern. I know random is an expensive class to spin up, but I can live with it.

Example:
There are 100 workflow instances that are scheduled to change state because a new workday has started. They all want to call sql at the same time.  Workflow Instances 90,91,and 92 make calls at the same time.  90 goes through just fine, but causes a deadlock for 91 and 92.

So 91 and 92 go into a delay activity, but before we go into the delay, we need to set a somewhat random number of seconds to wait.

All Workflow Instances have a minSeconds = 10 and maxSeconds = 600

Workflow Instance 1 : never calls our random generator

Workflow Instance 2 : never calls our random generator

Workflow Instance 90: never calls our random generator

Workflow Instance 91 : hits a deadlock calls generator which returns 63

Workflow Instance 92 : hits a deadlock calls generator which returns 123

Since 91 and 92 have to wait a different number of seconds, 91 waits less time, executes, then 60 seconds later 92 wakes up from the delay and calls our large transactional stored procedure and ... no more deadlocks.

```
  public sealed class RandomSecondsGenerator : CodeActivity<int>
    {
        [RequiredArgument]  
        public InArgument<int> MinSeconds { get; set; }

        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<int> MaxSeconds { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Usage,
        /// 1. Create a workflow variable, as an int, to hold the number of seconds.
        /// 2. Create a workflow variable, as a timespan, to hold the conversion from int to timespan.
        /// Call this Activity, and set the result to the in variable
        /// Use the assignment activity to convert the int to a timespan like below
        /// timespanToWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsToWait);
        /// Add the delay activity to the workflow ... 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected override int Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            var ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            var intArray = ticks.ToString().Reverse().Take(8);
            var backTogether = intArray.Aggregate("", (current, item) => current + item);
            var seed = Convert.ToInt32(backTogether);
            var rand = new Random(seed);

            var min = context.GetValue(MinSeconds);
            var max = context.GetValue(MaxSeconds);
            var secondsToWait = rand.Next(min, max);
            return secondsToWait;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  This would be a stronger question if it included an input/output usage example.  I.e. a running example.

Answer (score 1):

don't new it every time
it is expensive and is not as random as just keep using random
new Random() is based on a time seed

```
    private Random rand = new Random();
    protected override int Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        var min = context.GetValue(MinSeconds);
        var max = context.GetValue(MaxSeconds);
        var secondsToWait = rand.Next(min, max);
        return secondsToWait;
    }
```

OP said the many of the class are generated at once
Just create random once and pass it in the constructor

```
public class RandomSecondsGenerator 
{
    public int MinSeconds { get; set; }
    public int MaxSeconds { get; set; }
    private Random rand;
    protected int Execute(DateTime context)
    {
        var secondsToWait = rand.Next(MinSeconds, MaxSeconds);
        return secondsToWait;
    }
    public RandomSecondsGenerator(Random random)
    {
        rand = random;
    }
}
```

Comment: Moving the random out of the execute would not prevent it from being newed up  each time since each workflow is an independent actor.  Also since hundreds of workflow instances (that are independent) are essentially kicking off at the same time, the straight random call will produce the same number.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785744/how-do-i-seed-a-random-class-to-avoid-getting-duplicate-random-values

Comment: I also thought about just getting a guid, then pulling the first three integers out of the guid.

Comment: Then why not just have a shared static method or pass Random in the constructor?

Comment: Workflows in Workflow Foundation do not share anything. Making something static would just make it a singleton for one of the 100 instances of that workflow. A service outside of the workflow would need to be called for that to work, then that service would need to be maintained. Also workflows are instantiated via a WCF call. First serializing random is not practical. I suppose we could pass in a list of like 50 randomish numbers each workflow could independently work on, but that is more work too, I'd just rather the WF work it out on its own.

Comment: You cannot pass Random in a constructor or assign it with a set?    MinSeconds  is assign so it appears you have some means of access.   Don't see how pass a list of random is more work.   It is going to be a better list of random than what you hack up on the fly.

Comment: Since Workflow Foundation Serializes all data when it unloads a workflow, I don't think an instance of random will serialize to xml very well. Also, the issue is not random within a single workflow but different workflow instances running at the same time.

Comment: Then I don't get problem with send a List Int or random numbers.

Comment: Technically passing in a list would work, but then I have a violation of concerns, the various applications that kickoff my workflow don't care about my problem. And ... for the shared interface to change would require a change request process with 3rd parties which means meetings involving way too many people.  We would have to coordinate release schedules, and arrange for resources such as testers to write test cases and run manual tests across multiple deployment environments.  When I could just generate a random number in the workflow.

Comment: OK but it is tricky you get a good random seed.  But since no one is trying to hack you it does not need to be perfectly random.   Still think is a bad plan to generate the Random in the method call.

Comment: agreed, I think this only makes sense in this particular use case because every other option is worse.

Comment: You seem to feel pretty strongly about your design so I will let it go.  But I will don't like the design.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47134/discussion-between-eric-rohlfs-and-paparazzi).

Comment: I think the execution environment is what makes this issue so difficult, yes in the generic use case newing up a new random is an expensive operation, but the other pressure is Workflow Foundation which "unloads" from memory to a persistence layer when not actively working (not the same persistence layer having issues with.) Then, if all goes well, rehydrates the next time it needs to do work. The generic use case of random does not work.

Comment: I get you feel strongly about your design.  I have nothing additional to contribute.   Good luck.